# What are the rules for surname and pseudonymous for US and/or UK?

Tags: publications, journals

Given some deep personal issues I don't use my father's surname and aren't usually reconized or even cited by it. Although, in my country it's almost impossible to change your name or drop a surname. Neverthless, you can have more than one way of being cited registered in our national databese of researchers. I would like to know if in countries like US and UK it is possible to use one mother's surname or a pseudonymous when trying to get published at a journal.